# Finding out the CPU clock frequency (per core, per processor)

Tags: c++, cpu, cpu-speed

Programs like CPUz are very good at giving in depth information about the system (bus speed, memory timings, etc.)

However, is there a programmatic way of calculating the per core (and per processor, in multi processor systems with multiple cores per CPU) frequency without having to deal with CPU specific info.

I am trying to develop a anti cheating tool (for use with clock limited benchmark competitions) which will be able to record the CPU clock during the benchmark run for all the active cores in the system (across all processors.)

Comment: I've *tried* to do something like this before - as I'm author of one of such overclocker benchmarks. It's ***very*** hard. You can't just measure the frequency, you also have to make the system timers resistant to clock-tampering...

Comment: To add to my point. Methods to measure frequency involve hardware/performance counters. But you need an accurate measurement of a time-duration (such as the # of cycles in 1 second). However, when you're dealing with a determined cheaters, you cannot trust the results of any of these functions: `clock()`, `gettimeofday()`, `QueryPerformanceCounter()`, etc... as they can all be tampered with. (And I know how to tamper with them myself...)

Comment: Wow... that's revealing... did you finally decide on a strategy to at least make it difficult for someone to cheat 'easily' ?

Comment: I've expanded on this in the answer I just posted.

Comment: You this be tagged with a specific CPU family?

Comment: I need to handle various CPU families. Core 2/i7/i5/K8/K10/Bulldozer etc. Hence the generic tag.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095/assembly-cpu-frequency-measuring-algorithm

Comment: @KiD0M4N Yes, it is possible. On Intel CPUs, you need to use a kernel-mode WDM driver to do it. Source code and example for Intel chips can be found on my blog: http://www.dima.to/blog/?p=101

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'll expand on my comments here. This is too big and in-depth for me to fit in the comments.

What you're trying to do is very difficult - to the point of being impractical for the following reasons:

- There's no portable way to get the processor frequency. `rdtsc` does ***NOT*** always give the correct frequency due to effects such as SpeedStep and Turbo Boost.
- All known methods to measure frequency require an accurate measurement of time. However, a determined cheater can tamper with all the clocks and timers in the system.
- Accurately reading either the processor frequency as well as time in a tamper-proof way will require kernel-level access. This implies driver signing for Windows.

---

**There's no portable way to get the processor frequency:**

The "easy" way to get the CPU frequency is to call [`rdtsc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) twice with a fixed time-duration in between. Then dividing out the difference will give you the frequency.

The problem is that `rdtsc` does not give the true frequency of the processor. Because real-time applications such as games rely on it, `rdtsc` needs to be consistent through CPU throttling and Turbo Boost. So once your system boots, `rdtsc` will always run at the same rate (unless you start messing with the bus speeds with [SetFSB](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/overclocking-software,2059-3.html) or something).

For example, on my Core i7 2600K, `rdtsc` will always show the frequency at `3.4 GHz`. But in reality, it idles at `1.6 GHz` and clocks up to `4.6 GHz` under load via the overclocked Turbo Boost multiplier at `46x`.

But once you find a way to measure the true frequency, (or you're happy enough with `rdtsc`), you can easily get the frequency of each core using [thread-affinities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

**Getting the True Frequency:**

To get the true frequency of the processor, you need to access either the MSRs (model-specific registers) or the hardware performance counters.

These are kernel-level instructions and therefore require the use of a driver. If you're attempting this in Windows for the purpose of distribution, you will therefore need to go through the proper driver signing protocol. Furthermore, the code will differ by processor make and model so you will need different detection code for each processor generation.

Once you get to this stage, there are a variety of ways to read the frequency.

On Intel processors, the hardware counters let you count raw CPU cycles. Combined with a method of precisely measuring real time (next section), you can compute the true frequency. The MSRs give you access to other information such as the CPU frequency multiplier.

---

**All known methods to measure frequency require an accurate measurement of time:**

This is perhaps the bigger problem. You need a timer to be able to measure the frequency. A capable hacker will be able to tamper with all the clocks that you can use in C/C++.
This includes all of the following:

- `clock()`
- `gettimeofday()`
- `QueryPerformanceCounter()`
- etc...

The list goes on and on. In other words, you cannot trust any of the timers as a capable hacker will be able to spoof all of them. For example `clock()` and `gettimeofday()` can be fooled by changing the system clock directly within the OS. Fooling `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is harder.

**Getting a True Measurement of Time:**

All the clocks listed above are vulnerable because they are often derived off of the same system base clock in some way or another. And that system base clock is often tied to the system base clock - which can be changed after the system has already booted up by means of overclocking utilities.

So the only way to get a reliable and tamper-proof measurement of time is to read external clocks such as the [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) or the [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface). Unfortunately, these also seem to require kernel-level access.

---

**To Summarize:**

Building any sort of tamper-proof benchmark will almost certainly require writing a kernel-mode driver which requires certificate signing for Windows. This is often too much of a burden for casual benchmark writers.

This has resulted in a shortage of tamper-proof benchmarks which has probably contributed to the overall decline of the competitive overclocking community in recent years.

Comment: Is it possible to talk about this over email? I wish there was a Private Message feature here on SO.

Comment: Since I won't be able to disclose any details about the timer-hacks anyway, we could talk about it here or in chat. Unless there something else you want to discuss that needs to be in private.

Comment: We recently concluded a OC competition and had a fair share of suspect entries. I wanted to bounce some ideas of you on what I was planning on implementing as counter measures to at least help the judges get a better chance at detecting the cheats. I am at karan AT erodov DOT com please drop me a mail if we can take this line of discussion further :)

Comment: I am accepting this as answer as this has set my expectations right. I wish Frank didn't price his CPU-z SDK so high. Or provided a lower priced version for such usages. 1000+ euros is simply too much for me to afford for a free benchmark.

Comment: Here's a good thread about cheating benchmarks: (http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?46926-Faking-Benchmarks-The-Good-Benchmark-List-How-To-Spot-Cheats-and-More...) You can find my email through any of the links on my profile.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this has already been answered. I also realise this is basically a black art, so please take it or leave it - or offer feedback.

In a quest to find the clock rate on throttled (thanks microsft,hp, and dell) HyperV hosts (unreliable perf counter), and HyperV guests (can only get stock CPU speed, not current), I have managed, through trial error and fluke, to create a loop that loops exactly once per clock.

Code as follows - C# 5.0, SharpDev, 32bit, Target 3.5, Optimize on (crucial), no debuger active (crucial)

```
        long frequency, start, stop;
        double multiplier = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;//nano
        if (Win32.QueryPerformanceFrequency(out frequency) == false)
            throw new Win32Exception();

        Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1);
        const int gigahertz= 1000*1000*1000;
        const int known_instructions_per_loop = 1; 

        int iterations = int.MaxValue;
        int g = 0;

        Win32.QueryPerformanceCounter(out start);
        for( i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            g++;
            g++;
            g++;
            g++;
        }
        Win32.QueryPerformanceCounter(out stop);

        //normal ticks differs from the WMI data, i.e 3125, when WMI 3201, and CPUZ 3199
        var normal_ticks_per_second = frequency * 1000;
        var ticks = (double)(stop - start);
        var time = (ticks * multiplier) /frequency;
        var loops_per_sec = iterations / (time/multiplier);
        var instructions_per_loop = normal_ticks_per_second  / loops_per_sec;

        var ratio = (instructions_per_loop / known_instructions_per_loop);
        var actual_freq = normal_ticks_per_second / ratio;

        Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Perf counhter freq: {0:n}", normal_ticks_per_second));
        Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Loops per sec:      {0:n}", loops_per_sec));
        Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Perf counter freq div loops per sec: {0:n}", instructions_per_loop));
        Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Presumed freq: {0:n}", actual_freq));
        Console.WriteLine( String.Format("ratio: {0:n}", ratio));
```

Notes

- 25 instructions per loop if debugger is active
- Consider running a 2 or 3 seconds loop before hand to spin up the processor (or at least attempt to spin up, knowing how heavily servers are throttled these days)
- Tested on a 64bit Core2 and Haswell Pentium and compared against CPU-Z

Comment: Oh looks like 7 zip has a similar feature. Here is a run made on a 'Balanced' 2ghz 2012 server
> 7z b -mmt=1

7-Zip 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03

CPU Freq:   1032   1361   1015   1391   1361   1261   1264   1312  1396

RAM size:    4095 MB,  # CPU hardware threads:  12
RAM usage:    419 MB,  # Benchmark threads:      1

Comment: Nehalem and westmere - CPU model 26 and 44 - require known_instructions_per_loop = 2

Answer (score 2):

One of the most simple ways to do it is using `RDTSC`, but seeing as this is for anti-cheating mechanisms, I'd put this in as a kernel driver or a hyper-visor resident piece of code.

You'd probably also need to roll your own timing code**, which again can be done with `RDTSC` (QPC as used in the example below uses `RDTSC`, and its in fact very simple to reverse engineer and use a local copy of, which means to tamper with it, you'd need to tamper with your driver).

```
void GetProcessorSpeed()
{
    CPUInfo* pInfo = this;
    LARGE_INTEGER qwWait, qwStart, qwCurrent;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&qwStart);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&qwWait);
    qwWait.QuadPart >>= 5;
    unsigned __int64 Start = __rdtsc();
    do
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&qwCurrent);
    }while(qwCurrent.QuadPart - qwStart.QuadPart < qwWait.QuadPart);
    pInfo->dCPUSpeedMHz = ((__rdtsc() - Start) << 5) / 1000000.0;
}
```

** I this would be for security as @Mystical mentioned, but as I've never felt the urge to subvert low level system timing mechanisms, there might be more involved, would be nice if Mystical could add something on that :)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, this was posted long before everyone started moving to HPET based timing, however, IIRC I code this code from an old AMD sample for multi-core processors... As for that post, you should remove the horrid inline assembly and use the `__rtdsc` intrinsic :P

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter()` has been HPET-based on the multiprocessor kernel for a long long time, because TSC isn't synchronized across processors or cores.  But the main problem I was referring to in your code is (1) the busy-wait (2) not using actual elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

I've previously posted on this subject (along with a basic algorithm): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095/assembly-cpu-frequency-measuring-algorithm/6953905#6953905). To my knowledge the algorithm (see the discussion) is very accurate. For example, Windows 7 reports my CPU clock as 2.00 GHz, CPU-Z as 1994-1996 MHz and my algorithm as 1995025-1995075 kHz.

The algorithm performs a lot of loops to do this which causes the CPU frequency to increase to maximum (as it also will during benchmarks) so speed-throttling software won't come into play.

Additional info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432669/variance-in-rdtsc-overhead/7093075#7093075) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830883/cpu-cycle-count-based-profiling-in-c-c-linux-x86-64/4375598#4375598).

On the question of speed-throttling I really don't see it as a problem unless an application uses the speed values to determine elapsed times and that the times themselves are extremely important. For example, if a division requires x clock cycles to complete it doesn't matter if the CPU is running at 3 GHz or 300 MHz: it will still need x clock cycles and the only difference is that it will complete the division in a tenth of the time at @ 3 GHz.

Comment: Your solution uses RDTSC, which is not actual frequency on new CPUs.  Which you would have known if you read the existing answers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: If you checked out my first link you would have found that my method uses the (known) Windows system clock tick period to adjust the value obtained from multiple RTDSC readings. So I don't understand what you are getting at.

Comment: That calculates the RDTSC timescale, which is NOT the CPU clock frequency, as requested by this question.  See Mysticial's answer, specifically "The problem is that rdtsc does not give the true frequency of the processor"

Comment: A very tight loop calls time () over and over again until it increments. By doing this the CPU will increase its frequency to max which is then measured. Perhaps you can describe how this differs from "true frequency" which I cannot find any definition of. As Mysticial states there are many different frequencies available to a CPU. I'd say they are all "true." Or all "false."

Comment: Say you have a Haswell laptop, and the CPU has Turbo Boost with a 60% increase in frequency.  Your code, with the tight loop, will cause Turbo Boost to kick in, and the "true" frequency will be 160% of the "nominal" frequency.  But your code will report the nominal frequency.  RDTSC on new CPUs always uses the nominal frequency -- it's a timestamp, not a cycle counter.

Answer (score 1):

One should refer to this white paper: [Intel® Turbo Boost Technology in Intel® Core™ Microarchitecture (Nehalem) Based Processors](http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/INTC/0x0x348508/C9259E98-BE06-42C8-A433-E28F64CB8EF2/TurboBoostWhitePaper.pdf). Basically, produce several reads of the UCC fixed performance counter over a sample period T.

```
Relative.Freq = Delta(UCC)  / T

Where:
   Delta() = UCC @ period T
                 - UCC @ period T-1
```

Starting with Nehalem architecture, UCC increase and decrease the number of click ticks relatively to the Unhalted state of the core.

When SpeedStep or Turbo Boost are activated, the estimated frequency using UCC will be measured accordingly; while TSC remains constant. For instance, Turbo Boost in action reveals that Delta(UCC) is greater or equal to Delta(TSC)

Example in function `Core_Cycle` function at [Cyring | CoreFreq](http://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq/blob/master/corefreqd.c) GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CallNtPowerInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675(v=vs.85).aspx). Here's a [code sample](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/commit/17cbdf8b5e6730373a3b8eb9b0d4a8e477a04fee) from [putil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) project.
With this you can get current and max CPU frequency. As far as I know it's not possible to get per-CPU frequency.

Comment: This could be a good, practical answer for Windows systems. Unfortunately, there is no code to provide an example of what you are suggesting. Searching the cited MSDN page for "frequency" returns 0 hits.  As it stands it should probably be a comment.

Comment: There is a structure that hold current frequency (CurrentMhz member) under Windows - https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/windows/win32/power/processor-power-information-str