# Detect current CPU Clock Speed Programmatically on OS X?

Tags: macos, cpu, clock, cpu-speed

I just bought a nifty MBA 13"  Core i7.  I'm told the CPU speed varies automatically, and pretty wildly, too.  I'd really like to be able to monitor this with a simple app.

Are there any Cocoa or C calls to find the current clock speed, without actually affecting it?

Edit: I'm OK with answers using Terminal calls, as well as programmatic.

Thanks!

Comment: Not being particularly familiar with osx, but wouldn't there be a /proc type file system with that information? e.g. on Linux it's /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: There's no `/proc/` as far as I can tell.  There's a `system_profiler` command which gives the CPU speed listed on the box, but it doesn't change with the live updating clock speed

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351944/finding-out-the-cpu-clock-frequency-per-core-per-processor) for why this is extremely difficult to do.

Comment: Reading through now.  If it helps at all, I don't care about cheaters - since I won't be trying to cheat myself.  It's more of a curiosity tool.

Comment: Mystical, I'm about to put a bounty on this question.  Again, I don't need it to be cheat-proof - I just want to watch TurboBoost kick in (maybe write an app to play [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcDztfFXPww) every time it does)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this tool called "Intel Power Gadget". It displays IA frequency and IA power in real time.

http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/184535/intel-power-gadget-2.zip

Comment: This is really exactly what I wanted.  It even includes sample objective-c... Perfect!

Answer (score 15):

You can query the CPU speed easily via `sysctl`, either by command line:

```
sysctl hw.cpufrequency
```

Or via C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

int main() {
        int mib[2];
        unsigned int freq;
        size_t len;

        mib[0] = CTL_HW;
        mib[1] = HW_CPU_FREQ;
        len = sizeof(freq);
        sysctl(mib, 2, &freq, &len, NULL, 0);

        printf("%u\n", freq);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to return the "box advertised" speed (now 2.3ghz on my MBPR) but not the SpeedStep adjusted speed.

Comment: However, this is a useful and easy insight into the use of sysctl, so thank you for that!

Comment: Does not give current, but advertised speed. hw.cpufrequency, hw.cpufrequency_min, hw.cpufrequency_max all give the same.

Comment: This code will overflow the Hz on the new generation of > 4Ghz processors.  Need to use this instead. 
sysctlbyname("hw.cpufrequency_max", &speed, &len, NULL, 0); to support a 64-bit value for the frequency.

Comment: hmm `sysctl hw.cpufrequency` always reports 2500000000 for me.  The Intel Power Gadgetreports varying "IA" values from 1.3Ghz to 3.4GHz, wonder if there's a way to get more up to date values...

Comment: This does not work on my M1 MacBook

Comment: It seems that this entry is indeed missing for ARM-based systems. I guess that's due to their big.LITTLE CPU design (performance + efficiency cores), a common CPU frequency does not exist. The performance cores and efficiency cores run at different frequencies and both can scale their performance.

Answer (score 8):

Since it's an Intel processor, you could always use RDTSC. That's an assembler instruction that returns the current cycle counter — a 64bit counter that increments every cycle. It'd be a little approximate but e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint64_t rdtsc(void)
{
    uint32_t ret0[2];
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a"(ret0[0]), "=d"(ret0[1]));
    return ((uint64_t)ret0[1] << 32) | ret0[0];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    uint64_t startCount = rdtsc();
    sleep(1);
    uint64_t endCount = rdtsc();

    printf("Clocks per second: %llu", endCount - startCount);

    return 0;
}
```

Output 'Clocks per second: 2002120630' on my 2Ghz MacBook Pro.

Comment: On my MBA, it shows 1.8ghz, which is exactly right, but is there any way to force the i7 into turbo boost?

Comment: `rdtsc` is not a reliable way to measure a processor's clock speed. It does not adjust itself to turbo-boost/CPU-throttling (among other things).

Comment: @Mysticial on the contrary; it's usually advised as being an unreliable way to measure a CPU's clock speed _exactly because_ it is affected by turbo boost and CPU throttling.

Comment: @Tommy My tests suggests other wise. On my Xeon at stock 3.2 GHz `rdtsc` always says 3.2 GHz regardless of what I set the multiplier to (2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3.0, 3.2 GHz... all get reported as 3.2 GHz by `rdtsc`) `rdtsc` seems to change only when you start messing with the bus speeds.

Comment: Is there a way to determine what the multiplier is?  I'm interested in both knowing what speedstep pulls the CPU down to at idle and where TurboBoost puts the CPU under load.

Comment: @Tim, I think you have to access the BIOS to get bus-speed/multiplier information. There's no easy way to do that since there are hundreds of different motherboard/BIOS/CPU systems...

Comment: @Mystical I've seen some apps around which claim to find the information about current core speed, including Intel's own app (on Windows), but no source code anywhere.  I'm sure there's a way to do it - Intel has a [big ole' pdf with sample code](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/application-notes/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.pdf) but I can't get it to compile - though I'll continue trying.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kernel extension written by "flAked" which logs the cpu p-state to the kernel log.
http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=258612

maybe you could contact him for the code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work correctly on OSX.
However, it doesn't work on Linux, where sysctl is deprecated and KERN_CLOCKRATE is undefined.

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

  int mib[2];
  size_t len;
  mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
  mib[1] = KERN_CLOCKRATE;
  struct clockinfo clockinfo;
  len = sizeof(clockinfo);
  int result = sysctl(mib, 2, &clockinfo, &len, NULL, 0);
  assert(result != -1);
  log_trace("clockinfo.hz: %d\n", clockinfo.hz);
  log_trace("clockinfo.tick: %d\n", clockinfo.tick);
```

Comment: Running `sysctl kern.clockrate` at command line gives me a steady `kern.clockrate: { hz = 100, tick = 10000, tickadj = 2, profhz = 100, stathz = 100 }` where the Intel CPU profiler is showing varying values, so I don't think this works with the speedstep adjustments.